# Why this XPath sentence is wrong for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, xpath, chickenfoot

```
click(new XPath("/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/SPAN[1]/SPAN[2]/#text[1]"));
```

..or

```
var foo = document.evaluate("/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/SPAN[1]/SPAN[2]/#text[1]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
```

Result to:

```
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"  location: "chrome://chickenfoot/content/chickenscratch.js Line: 2"]
```

Firefox 3.6, XPath generated by Chickenfoot's XPath generator at GMail's button 'Older'.

What is this kind of XPath and why it is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `#text` element. To get the text content, use `text()`, i.e.

```
"/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/..../SPAN[2]/text()"
```